# Have JS code, but need to call it from C#

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf

I have a large .js file, with a function and a method. I am pretty green with JS. I have a WCF web method that I would like to call this js method... The example in the JS file is to call it like this:

> ```
> var wmm = new WorldMagneticModel();
>
> then
>
> var dec = wmm.declination(0.0, 59.0, -2.0, 2010.5);
> ```

I see the method call in the function, within the js file:

```
WorldMagneticModel.prototype.declination = function(altitudeKm, latitudeDegrees, longitudeDegrees, yearFloat)
```

I would like this method to be available to my c# web service. Is there anyway to do it? Maybe I need to make an ASP.net page, embed the js, and call it?

HOpe someone can assist.

Comment: You want to call Javascript on the client browser from a C# webservice? WCF services can be called from many clients and there's no guarantee that there will be a browser involved

Comment: When in the event model of your application do you expect this to be called?  How is the server-side code going to know when or where to call something on the client-side?  You're lacking a fundamental understanding of the request/response nature of web applications.  The client makes a request, the server code runs on the server in response to that request, which ultimately results in a response back to the client.  At that point the server-side code is done.  The client is entirely disconnected.  Client-side code needs to be called by the client-side events (other client-side code).

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the [_Java_ `WorldMagneticModel`](http://seesea.sourceforge.net/wmm2010/javadoc/org/noaa/wmm/WorldMagneticModel.html)? Java and JavaScript are radically different

Comment: @Basic - no. It's a js file. http://www.bdcc.co.uk/Gmaps/WorldMagneticModel.js

Comment: @David, I have methods in my WCF service that return data about a GPS location. The calculation for something, I can only find in a ,js file. I want to call that JS file, which returns a single number, and then add that to an object which gets returned to the calling application.

Comment: @Craig: You could perhaps port the functionality to C#.  Or maybe use something like node.js to run the code in another server-side application and your .NET application would call that other application as a service.  (Essentially the .NET app would be the "client" and the node app would be the "server", they'd just both be running on the same machine.)  This is mostly conjecture, though.  I've never actually done that.

Comment: Yeah @David. I was thinking of that. My very basic idea was to simply make an ASP.Net page, which uses the js file, and the response from that page is simple something like <HTML>1.5</HTML>. I can then parse that response?

Comment: @Craig: Parse it using what?  You'd need something to execute the JavaScript code, which in that case would be a web browser.  .NET has some built-in browser-like objects, but do they execute JavaScript and modify the DOM accordingly?  That approach may avoid adding another technology to the stack, but it seems like it adds a lot of complexity.

Comment: OK,is it possible to put the javascript into a .js file, add it to an ASP.Net project, add the script to a aspx page, and call that js in the OnLoad, passing it parameters and getting the value returned from the JS - and display it on the page?

Comment: @Craig, yes, you can do exactly that.  Perhaps you should explore that approach and come back with any questions you might have after trying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run it on the server side, you could use [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/):

```
JintEngine engine = new JintEngine();
// source should be a string containing the contents of your JavaScript file
engine.Run(source);
engine.SetParameter("altitudeKm", altitudeKm);
engine.SetParameter("latitudeDegrees", latitudeDegrees);
engine.SetParameter("longitudeDegrees", "longitudeDegrees");
engine.SetParameter("yearFloat", yearFloat);
var result = engine.Run(@"
    var wmm = new WorldMagneticModel();
    return wmm.declination(altitudeKm, latitudeDegrees, longitudeDegrees, yearFloat);
");
return result;
```

Comment: What is 'source' in 'engine.Run(source)? A JS file?

Comment: @Craig: `source` should be the contents of your `WorldMagneticModel.js` file.

Comment: Thanks. I have it in a js file in the project - can I read the contents into a string, and load it like that? So that I don't have to have loads of js in my c# file?

Comment: Getting "An unexpected error occured while parsing the script". Should the parameters somehow be parameterised? How does the parameters get inserted into the engine.run?

Comment: @Craig: Unfortunately, I haven't personally used Jint so I don't know why it wouldn't be working. Perhaps try small bits of the code to see what it fails on.